# sharing credentials between some projects

Tags: google-cloud-nl

- project-A enables Natural Language API.
- project-B doesn't.
- project-A's service account is allowed to access both project-A and project-B.

Under this situation, the following step for a sample script [like this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/blob/master/language/quickstart.rb) should work:

1. export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/credentials.json"
2. run the script

Where, the credentials.json contains:

```
...
"project_id": "project-A",
...
```

Now, when I modify it as follows:

```
"project_id": "project-B",
```

Then,

Q1) I thought the script failed because project-B Natural Language API has not yet been enabled.  **However**, it works, why?  Does this actually access project-A's NL-API?

Q2) Is there any way to check access log at GCP? Then, I can check which project the script runs.

Q3) I think it is usual approach to share credentials.json between project-A and project-B and to switch project under some situations.  At Dialogflow, each API need to pass project-ID so that credentials.json sharing works.  How about NL-API to switch project with sharing credentials?

Comment: About Q2), I found that GCP console > API & Service > Dashboard shows access log.  When I changed project_id of credentials.json and run the sample script, there is no change on access.  Project_id in credentials.json is just information.

Comment: If you set that project_id to something random, it'd still work?

Comment: Yes, it still works.  As well as regarding to access log I commented for Q2 by myself, it looks project_id is not referred.